# How to format the dates in a sql statement

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I run a `select *` statement I get two different date formats.

How would I format the all the days with out specifically calling the date columns.

Comment: What are the two formats and what are the two types of columns in your database?

Comment: If you're not going to provide--and if necessary, format--a column list, you are relying on the underlying schema to define what is returned.

Comment: And where are you viewing the output? After displaying with C# or is this just in management studio?

Comment: This isn't answering your question but please don't use "SELECT *" without a very good reason. Only retrieve the columns you need and no more.

Comment: Select * is a SQL antipattern and should not be used in production code even when you want all the columns. And it should never be used if you have a join since at least one column is repeated. That just wastes network and server resources for no reason at all. Honestly how hard is it to drag the columns over from the object browser?

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the underlying data types of your dates, you can't, from SQL, manipulate the format of the record set without explicitly doing a cast/convert on your select:

```
SELECT CAST(SomeDate1 as DATETIME), CAST(SomeDate2 as DATETIME) FROM User
```

Or using `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, SomeDate1, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR, SomeDate2, 101) FROM User
```

Assuming 101 is the format you want (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for the various formats).

Comment: I suggest format 121 as the most reliable/universal `CONVERT(varchar(23), someDate, 121)` gives '2012-01-25 15:09:23.003'. This sorts sensibly as text, and converts reliably back to a datetime regardless of locale.